# How to remove a string that got a specific character in from a list in python

Tags: python, list

i got a list with different string. Many of them got a special character in f.e. 'X'. How to remove the strings that got the specific character in from a list in python.

f.e.
['ABCXDU','ZUTRC','AZUX','ABNIU']
the output i want --> ['ZUTRC','ABNIU'] strings of that list dont have x in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
[x for x in some_list if "X" not in x]
```

to build a new list of only those without `X` in them

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [s for s in your_input_list if 'X' not in s]
```

or you can do like this:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda s: 'X' not in s, your_input_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension

`new_list = [item for item in my_list if "X" not in item]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
words = ["ABCXDU","ZUTRC","AZUX","ABNIU"]
n = []
for w in words:
    if w.find("X") == -1:
        n.append(w)
print(n)
```

What this does is that it considers the character as a substring and then checks if it exists or not. If it does not exist, we add the word to a new list and at the end print the new list